# Facebook Sharing Debugger Strange Behavior

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook, express

I have a Nodejs App built with Express, and React.js for this scenario.

Right now I have two url paths '/products/:id' and '/blogs/:id'. When these urls are hit with the facebook scraper they return the meta tags to facebook.

```
socialRouter.get('/products/:id', socialRouterController.getProduct);
socialRouter.get('/blogs/:id', socialRouterController.getBlog);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var ua = req.headers['user-agent'];
    //console.log(ua);
    if (/^(facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|WhatsApp|Pinterest|LinkedInBot|GoogleBot)/gi.test(ua)) {
        console.log('social media was found');
        socialRouter(req, res, next);
    }
    else {
        //console.log('No social media crawler was found');
        next();
    }
})
```

This is the straight up controller code:

```
getProduct: async function(req, res) {

    console.log('Hello, we are sending you the html for social media sharing')

    var maindomain = process.env.BASE_URL

    console.log(req.params.id);

    //res with data after db query

},

getBlog: async function(req, res) {

    console.log('Sending blog to facebook for media sharing');

    var maindomain = process.env.BASE_URL;

    console.log(req.params.id);

    //res with data after db query

},
```

My problem I'm having is that for blogs sometimes the url when requested from facebook is straight up undefined.

When I click the 'Scrape Again' button on facebook this happens:

```
social media was found
Sending blog to facebook for media sharing
{ id: 'osBKKvqFzG2MJA35XOSxgXTI' }
osBKKvqFzG2MJA35XOSxgXTI
social media was found
Sending blog to facebook for media sharing
{ id: 'undefined' }
undefined
```

This is weird behavior that I can't explain. When I do the exact same thing to the product page, this is the behavior:

```
social media was found
Hello, we are sending you the html for social media sharing
{id: '0htUBsMbhXi7pTjAs6DqWHaE'}
social media was found
Hello, we are sending you the html for social media sharing
{id: '0htUBsMbhXi7pTjAs6DqWHaE'}
```

This has been happening consistently, and I can't explain it.

I thought it could've been my routes, but they're inoffensive.

```
<Route exact path="/products/:id" render={(routeProps) => <ProductPage {...routeProps} />} />
<Route exact path="/blogs/:id" render={(routeProps) => <PublicBlog {...routeProps} /> } />
```

If anyone has any clue as to why the facebook scraper would behave differently with the exact same conditions, please let me know!

Comment: What URLs are Facebook scraping?

Comment: The URLs in question are for example this one: https://bazaah.com/blogs/osBKKvqFzG2MJA35XOSxgXTI When using the sharing debugger, it gives a 400 error. Using the scraping API or curl with the facebookexternalhit user-agent return expected behavior.

Comment: If you look in the share debugger it explains why.  https://bazaah.com/blogs/osBKKvqFzG2MJA35XOSxgXTI contains a og:url =  https://bazaah.com/blogs/undefined/ so Facebook redirects to that.

Comment: Yeah it seems the graph api gets the correct result, but then the sharing debugger gets a different result. Its a curious result that I'm seeing. The og:url being undefined would imply a back-end problem on my end. But then why do the product paths have nothing off about them? It's a real conundrum that probably isn't on Facebooks end.